# Impact of migrating GCP projects into an organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to migrate projects with no organization into an organization. I have some dashboards connected to big query in these projects. I'd like to know if I will have some impact in these dashboards/connections when migrating.

Comment: As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manage-billing-account#create_a_new_billing_account) setting of Account  type is permanent and maybe used for TAX, VAT and identity verification. I'm not sure, how can you migrate the Individual account to Business?

Comment: Hi @Mahboob, maybe I was not clear. When i say migrating personal account to a business account I mean migrating projects with no organization into an organization. I modified my question to make me clear.

Comment: If you are moving project A to Organization O the permissions for project A IAM will not change unless there is an Organization policy constraint. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints Your question does not provide details on the dashboards but I expect everything will continue to work as before.

Comment: @JohnHanley, as you said, everything is ok after migrating. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the GCP [doc](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing?hl=en) you can migrate all of cloud projects using Cloud Console, the Resource Manager API, or the gcloud command-line tool. Migrating Cloud Billing accoint into an Organization doesn't [affect project services](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing#migrating_existing_billing_accounts). Please note that, it is the user’s responsibility to make sure that IAM and organization policies are consistent when projects are moved into the organization.

Comment: Thanks for helping @Mahboob! Dashboards are working as before! I dindn't have problems with connections or permissions.